# swift - unwrapping optional with "guard let"

Tags: swift, option-type, guard

I am parsing `JSON` data. After I start getting `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` errors. I tried to use `guard` statement.

But again I am getting the same error.

```
guard let articleTitle = self.articles?[indexPath.row]["title"].string! else {return}
```

I simulate nil value like this:

```
guard let articleTitle = self.articles?[indexPath.row]["t"].string! else {return}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `guard`ing `let` an unwrapped optional is a contradiction in terms. It makes the `guard` statement useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn’t make much sense to force unwrap the optional in a conditional let assingment. Remove the `!`:

```
guard let articleTitle = self.articles?[indexPath.row]["title"].string else {return}
```

Otherwise the right-hand side will never produce nil but crash.